# I am trying to create an Excel 2013 macro to search through workbooks for a specifed worksheet of words

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to vba and can not get the user determined workbook - worksheet to save to a variable. I was going to use the variable to control the loops as it searches through the excel sheets for the words. With the below snippet the user is prompted and can select a file that shows up as a string format for the checkReport variable. But the Checksheet will not save.

```
 Dim CheckReport As Variant
 Dim Checksheet As Object

 'Open the target workbook
  CheckReport = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xls*", _
  1, "Select Your CheckList File To Open", , False)

   'Saves the Worksheet in order to control the loop
   If CheckReport <> False Then
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=CheckReport
     Set Checksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

  End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Workbooks.Open()` returns a reference to the workbook (assuming there wasn't an error).  You can assign that to a variable like this:

```
Set Checksheet = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=CheckReport).Worksheets("Sheet1")
```